# Is there a way to emit the DLL even with reference errors in the compilation

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I would like to create a dll from c# code even there are reference errors in the compilation. Is it possible to create it from Roslyn API. I could see "tolerateErrors" in EmitOptions class but it didn't work.

```
EmitOptions emitOptions = new EmitOptions(tolerateErrors: true);
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var emitResult = compilation.Emit(stream, options: emitOptions);
```

Comment: That makes no sense.  If there are errors, the compiler has no idea what to emit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @SLaks. Why compiler worries about reference errors always. I changed the question by removing syntax part. :)

Comment: The compiler needs references to do things like overload resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create what's called a *reference assembly*, I believe. You just need to set the `metadataOnly` flag on your `EmitOptions`:

```cs
var emitOptions = new EmitOptions(metadataOnly: true, tolerateErrors: true);
```

Such assemblies can only be used to resolve references though. They don't contain any actual code (all method bodies are replaced with `throw null;`).